# Access management url getting redirect to idp url

Tags: sites-9.5, azure, access-management

We installed Access management and configured Azure OpenID provider.
When we hit the CMS URL first URL#1 popup and once we gave email id, it redirects URL#2(idp URL) and browser pop up appears, then again I need to login with my email and password.
is this expected behavior or we can avoid the second step by any configuration.

URL#1: https://login.microsoftonline.com/413dff2b-33e8-4670-92a8-f643afbb243a/oauth2/authorize?client_id=bdgggdgd9702f4-e804-4215-8f45-bc2dsffefbe75b8c&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftridion-dev.abc.net%3A8443%2Faccess-management%2Fazure%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile%20email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=6dgfgsd53806bjo&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.5.0.0&sso_reload=true

URL#2: https://idp.abc.com/adfs/ls/wia?client-request-id=c00cdfdf4f9a-1a36-4f59-bab6-b9bd363c97d1&wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn%3afederation%3aMicrosoftOnline&wctx=LoginOptions%3D3%26estsredirect%3d2%26estsrequest%3drQQIARAAfwf0&cbcxt=&username=prasanna.gollamudi%40abc.com&mkt=&lc=

Comment: I'm curious how you see things working without the second step.  Do you want users to log in without authenticating themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reached to SDL support, they verified and mentioned this as expected behavior